# PHP cURL how to check if my request was blocked?

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I use cURL on this asmx URL: http://ltcmobile.webhop.biz:2016/ereloadws/service.asmx
success in localhost, but when I upload the file to my live server, it will return bool(false)

However I tried changing the submission URL and my request to other asmx URL, I tried http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx and it does work on localhost and live server.

Does this mean my connection was blocked by http://ltcmobile.webhop.biz:2016/ereloadws/service.asmx? Anyway I can check and confirm this?

**curl_getinfo result:**

localhost:
Array ( [url] => http://ltcmobile.webhop.biz:2016/ereloadws/service.asmx [content_type] => text/xml; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 230 [request_size] => 525 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.109 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0.063 [pretransfer_time] => 0.063 [size_upload] => 393 [size_download] => 479 [speed_download] => 4394 [speed_upload] => 3605 [download_content_length] => 479 [upload_content_length] => 393 [starttransfer_time] => 0.109 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => 175.139.27.203 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 2016 [local_ip] => 192.168.1.102 [local_port] => 52286 )

live server:
Array ( [url] => http://ltcmobile.webhop.biz:2016/ereloadws/service.asmx [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 9.7E-5 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => 175.139.27.203 [certinfo] => Array ( ) )

**curl call:**

```
$xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
   <SendRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <ResellerAccount>*******</ResellerAccount>
     <RefNum>******</RefNum>
   </SendRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$URL = "http://ltcmobile.webhop.biz:2016/ereloadws/service.asmx";

$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($output);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there could be so many reasons.  A good point to start investigating is to actually looking at the curl info available. Look here for details **[curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)**. That could give you a hint as to where to continue your investigation.

Comment: Hi @YvesLeBorg I edit my question with curl_getinfo result, Thanks!!

Comment: your server request does not look like it is traveling. Try to look at curl_error to, see what it says about this. Is port 2016 outbound open on your server ? can you (from server) ping `175.139.27.203 ` ?  so much to do, so little time. :)

Comment: Hi @YvesLeBorg tried curl_error it return "couldn't connect to host"  about the ping i will request my host and update you ;)

Comment: Please post the full code you are using to make the curl call.

Comment: Hi @BenShoval curl call code added above, not sure if that is the issue as this is working in localhost and also work in live with other asmx URL + request, Thanks!

Comment: Hi @YvesLeBorg you are correct it is because my host block port 2016, can you post your answer so I can select it as the answer thanks a lot have a great day !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your curl_getinfo outputs, it seems your server-side request does not look like it is traveling. Also look at curl_error to, see what it says about this.

You probably have an outbound  communications issue from your server. Is port 2016 outbound open on your server ? can you (from server) ping 175.139.27.203 ?

Comment: This was the issue, I just knew that http://ltcmobile.webhop.biz:2016 means our host should also need to open port 2016 , also I learn to use curl_getinfo and curl_error 
Thanks a lot !!